# Syntax error on token "double", @ expected

Tags: java, eclipse

Im setting up a simple method and I keep getting the following error:

Syntax error on token "double", @ expected

Here is my method:

```
public double Calculate ()  {

 }
```

The method is just a simple calculation. I have even tried a very simple method like this:

```
 public void Calculate ()  {

 }
```

Syntax error on token "void", @ expected

Eclipse is still giving me the error. What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Eclipse is an IDE that supports multiple languages - which is it you're trying to write, and have you saved the file so Eclipse knows which one it should be parsing your code as?

Comment: Im working in Java and the file works just fine until I add the new method declaration.

Comment: Show use the whole code.. something nearby may be effecting things.

Comment: I had to reinstall Eclipse...it went downhill from this point, but it is working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs in Java class file without class declaration.

If you want Java class (and probably you want some) you need to do something like this:

```java
public class TestClass {
    public double calculate() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

If you miss class declaration both your error occurs:

```java
public double calculate() {
}
```

There are 2 errors showing:

- Syntax error on token "double", @ expected
- Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeader

There are also [The Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) you should learn with language too f.e. method names start with lowercase letter.

Answer (score 0):

The method `public double Calculate()` needs to have a value returned that is of type double

Comment: Still getting the same error and now Im also getting the following error: Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeader